# Will there be a class redefinition if a class is included via two include files indirectly?

Tags: c++

if I include class definition file classA.h in classB.h and classC.h, then if classD.h includes both classB.h and classC.h, will there be a class redefinition?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just [asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917488/c-include-header-problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that you correctly use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), this shouldn't be a problem.  In particular, if you ensure that `#include`-ing the same file twice is idempotent (`#include`-ing the same header twice is the same as `#include`-ing it once), then this won't cause a problem.  When `classD.h` includes `classB.h`, it will include `classA.h`.  When it then tries to include `classC.h` and `classC.h` tries to include `classA.h`, then nothing happens.  This is fine, though, because `classC.h` can see `classA.h` because it was already included.